# VB.NET : Battery percentage code isn't updated in real-time

Tags: .net, windows, vb.net, timer, battery

I made a program with Visual Studio to display battery percentage using a Label and ProgressBar, the problem I had is that the battery percentage isn't updated in real time although I already put `TimerBattery.Tick()` in `Form_Load`, I have to relaunch my app to update the information. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

```
Dim psBattery As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus
Dim perFull As Single = psBattery.BatteryLifePercent

 Private Sub TimerBattery_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerBattery.Tick
        If perFull * 100 >= 100 Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = 100
        ElseIf perFull * 100 < 100 Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = perFull * 100
        End If
        If psBattery.PowerLineStatus = PowerLineStatus.Online Then
            LabelBatt.Text = "Battery " & perFull * 100 & "%"
            LabelBatt2.Text = perFull * 100 & "%, charging"
        ElseIf psBattery.PowerLineStatus = PowerLineStatus.Offline Then
            LabelBatt.Text = "Battery " & perFull * 100 & "%"
            LabelBatt2.Text = perFull * 100 & "%, not charging"
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the Timer's interval? Did you try to set a breakpoint in this code to see if it is called at the specified timer's interval?

Comment: I didn't set any, because it's working well to show clock in real-time so i thought in this case would work too

Comment: There is a default of 100ms on the timer. A really short interval. Also, by default the Timer is not Enabled. So I suggest you to change the Interval property to at least 1000ms and check if the Enabled property is set or not (or if you call the Timer Start method) then put a breakpoint into the Tick event to check if the code is executed or not

Comment: If `perFull * 100` is not `>= 100` then the `Else` case will automatically handle the case `perFull * 100 < 100`. So, a simple `Else` will do it. No `ElseIf` required.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try

Comment: The breakpoint showed the perFull value (that means it's executed, right?), already set the interval to 1000 too. But nothing worked. Interestingly, the second IfThen case partially worked. It showed whether power source is plugged or not, but the percentage stuck.

Comment: What happens if you move the two lines that initializes _psBattery_ and _perFull_ inside the Tick event? This way the value is read at each Tick event and not just one time at the creation of the form

Comment: Moved it, and it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move at least the line that initializes the *perFull* variable inside the Tick event. Otherwise the *perFull* value is calculated just one time when you open the form class.

```
Dim psBattery As PowerStatus = SystemInformation.PowerStatus

Private Sub TimerBattery_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerBattery.Tick

    ' Now at each Tick event you read the PowerStatus value and
    ' execute the Tick logic with the correct value        
    Dim perFull As Single = psBattery.BatteryLifePercent

    If perFull * 100 >= 100 Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = 100
    ElseIf perFull * 100 < 100 Then
        ProgressBar1.Value = perFull * 100
    End If
    If psBattery.PowerLineStatus = PowerLineStatus.Online Then
        LabelBatt.Text = "Battery " & perFull * 100 & "%"
        LabelBatt2.Text = perFull * 100 & "%, charging"
    ElseIf psBattery.PowerLineStatus = PowerLineStatus.Offline Then
        LabelBatt.Text = "Battery " & perFull * 100 & "%"
        LabelBatt2.Text = perFull * 100 & "%, not charging"
    End If

End Sub
```